# Why use *λx.x* instead of *f(x)*?

Tags: lambda-calculus, formal-grammar

In my semantics class, we're learning about using (abusing?) lambda calculus. So far the professor hasn't imparted any reason for using *λx.x* instead of using *f(x)*.

- Why use lambdas instead of basic functions?
- Why do mathematicians notate lambdas, *λx.x*; wouldn't *λ(x)* suffice?

Thank you

Comment: Anonymous functions are great.

Comment: It is shorter and you do not have to pick a name for it so there is no danger of name clash. It maybe also more readable in context.

Comment: One could also ask then why don't we use '(x)f' instead of 'f(x)' (postpositioning the function name makes it easier to interpret composition of functions in a left to right reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative notation for $\lambda$ is $\mapsto$. For instance, the following mean the same:

- $x\mapsto x+3$
- $\lambda x. x+3$

You could have defined it like $f(x) = x+3$, but then $f$ becomes an entity in your discourse.   And having to name every function you need becomes cumbersome after a while, especially if they are of no particular interest and you just want to convey their correspondence.

To understand why you need to write $\lambda x.x+3$ instead of simply $\lambda(x+3)$, consider the following function definition (given in the three different notations we are addressing):

- $x\mapsto (y\mapsto x-y)$
- $\lambda x.(\lambda y. x-y)$
- $f(x) = g(x,\cdot)$ where $g(x,y) = x-y$

In all of the above definitions it is clear that $x$ is the first argument and $y$ is the second. But, if you write $\lambda(\lambda (x-y))$, then that information is lost precisely because we have not associated with each $\lambda$ its corresponding argument, i.e. $\lambda(\lambda(x-y))$ could stand for both $\lambda x.(\lambda y.x-y)$ and $\lambda y.(\lambda x.x-y)$.